# Div goes back to hidden after animation

Tags: css

I have a hidden div and I want to show 2 seconds after page load. 
I was able to show the hidden div with this code

```
    #itemL{
        visibility: hidden;
        animation: popAnim 1s ease;
        animation-delay: 2s;
    }
    @keyframes popAnim{
        0%{
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100%{
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
```

but after the animation it goes back to hidden.
How do I make it visible permanently after the animation?

Comment: You don't have "a json". You have an object. Json is a way of passing object data as a string.

Comment: At least one issue I see is that you are trying to access the pictureList object keys by index. You can't do this, unless you do something like `Object.values(pictureList)[i]`.

Comment: The approach here is confusing. Do you really need to take an option value and search for that substring in all your object property values? Why don't you describe your larger goal in your question. We can probably help better that way than trying to answer this oddly specific question.

Comment: can help you if you share stackblitz code

Comment: Unless the pictureList object is being used elsewhere, I don't see the value in storing the image path strings in a structure at all since your select options are hardcoded. Just give your options the exact value you need, and in the change callback use that directly to supply your image src attribute.

Comment: As you have mixed array and object syntax as mentioned by @wizloc I have included both solutions in my answer and a preffered method which I would suggest to keep you code readable and easy to follow/debug (dependent on if you can edit the `pictureList` variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to reference an object with an index `i` (when you want to be using the value `val`) and then get the file. You are mixing up arrays and objects.

You also have all your object keys called the same thing, so only the last one will count

You need to have different attribute names for each file and do the following:
`jQuery('img').attr("src", pictureList["file" + val]);`

```
  var pictureList = {
      "file1": "/data/3/EAs.jpeg",
      "file2": "/data/3/blooddraw.jpeg",
      "file3":"/data/3/households.jpeg",
    };

    jQuery('#targetVsRecruit').change(function () {
        var val = jQuery('#targetVsRecruit').val();
        jQuery('img').attr("src", pictureList["file" + val ]);
    })
```

```
    <select id="targetVsRecruit">
       <option value="file1">EAs</option>
       <option value="file2">Blood Draws</option>
       <option value="file3">Households</option>

    </select>
```

or simply convert to an array and use index, but not both as you had before
`jQuery('img').attr("src", pictureList[val]);`

```
  var pictureList = [
      "/data/3/EAs.jpeg",
      "/data/3/blooddraw.jpeg",
      "/data/3/households.jpeg",
    ];
```

```
    <select id="targetVsRecruit">
       <option value="0">EAs</option>
       <option value="1">Blood Draws</option>
       <option value="2">Households</option>
    </select>
```

---

The best approach would be to have a meaningful value and key in an object -

`jQuery('img').attr("src",pictureList[i]);`

```
  var pictureList = {
      "EAs": "/data/3/EAs.jpeg",
      "blooddraw": "/data/3/blooddraw.jpeg",
      "households":"/data/3/households.jpeg",
    };

    jQuery('#targetVsRecruit').change(function () {
        var val = jQuery('#targetVsRecruit').val();
        jQuery('img').attr("src", pictureList[val]);
    })
```

```
    <select id="targetVsRecruit">
       <option value="EAs">EAs</option>
       <option value="blooddraw">Blood Draws</option>
       <option value="households">Households</option>

    </select>
```